# Understanding coercion

Tags: ruby, matrix, coercion

I've submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/pull/685), which modifies the `Matrix` class so that additions can be performed with real numbers:

`Matrix[ [25, 93], [-1, 66] ] + 5`

The `Matrix` class has a method `+()`, which is called in this case.

I would also like users to be able to change the order of the operation to

`5 + Matrix[ [25, 93], [-1, 66] ]`

The `Matrix` [class](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/lib/matrix.rb) seems to support this order of operation for the `*()` method and I'm unsure how to implement this for the `+()` method.

Comment: This is done with `coerce` method. It is already implemented for Matrix with Numeric values, so all should work fine. Have you tried it?

Comment: @BroiSatse Yep, if I run a unit test, it only passes if the `Fixnum` is at the end, otherwise I get an exception: `ExceptionForMatrix::ErrOperationNotDefined: Operation(+) can't be defined: Fixnum op Matrix`

Comment: @CarySwoveland My [pull request](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/pull/685) modified the code so that operations with a scalar (real number) are allowed. However, it only works if the number is at the end and not at the beginning. I would like it to work both ways.

Comment: @migu - Look at matrix.rb, line 1514.

Comment: Sorry, missed the link...

Comment: @BroiSatse Had a look at the `Scalar < Numeric` class but I don't get what calls it and how it exactly works for example when doing `5 * Matrix[ [25, 93], [-1, 66] ]`. Can you break it down for me? I have zero experience with coercion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coercion is handled with `coerce` method. This method is to return two elements for which given operator/method is to be retried. `Matrix` defines `coerce` like:

```
def coerce(other)
  case other
  when Numeric
    return Scalar.new(other), self
  else
    raise TypeError, "#{self.class} can't be coerced into #{other.class}"
  end
end
```

Note however that it is not changing the order of the operands, but rather converts numeric value into a `Scalar` class. Hence, ruby seeing `5 + Matrix[...]` will execute `Scalar.new(5) + Matrix[...]`.

`Scalar` class is defined within the same file and defines its own set of operators, including `+` and '-'. So what you need to do is get rid of line `Scalar.Raise ErrOperationNotDefined, "+", @value.class, other.class` and enforce your code here, for example with `other + self`

Answer (score 2):

This is too long for a comment and it is an answer of a kind. But instead of explaining how `#coerce` works, which anyone can read up from the documentation, I would like to tell you, don't do it. And by that, I mean

1. don't overload `Matrix#+` with addition of a number to all the elements, and
2. don't modify `Matrix#coerce`.

The reason for 1. is that you think you are adding a capability. But you are also losing something. Matrices can generally be summed up only with other matrices of the same dimension. If you make a mistake and try to sum up matrices of different dimension, or try to sum up a matrix with some unrelated object, you will get an error. This error is a service to the programmer. It is a welcome reminer that allows us to discover early that we made a mistake, that we are trying to add an incompatible object to a matrix. This error allows us to detect the problem early. If you start overloading `Matrix#+`, you are gaining new functionality, but you are also losing warnings, the language is becoming more fragile. If you really want to add a number to each element, define a new method, such as

---

```
class Matrix
  def add_to_each n
    self + self.map { n }
  end
end
```

---

As for 2., again you are fragilizing 2 objects: `Matrix::Scalar`, and numeric objects. You think you are doing a service, making `Matrix` more useful. But writing

```
Matrix[[1, 2], [3, 4]].map { |e| e + 5 }
```

is not difficult at all. Imo, sweetening this syntax by overloading `+` is a net loss. I know you have already done the work, but publish it as a gem, do not pollute the core with this feature creep.

Comment: He is not overloading `Matrix#+` method, he is modyfying it. Current implementation do a case over operand type and behaves accordingly, so it is safe to change it for Numeric case. Anyway, +1 for suggesting creating a gem instead of modifying the core.

Comment: Thanks for agreeing with me in that last point. People should be free to decide whether they want this new functionality. The gem name should be something like `matrix_extensions`. Also, John Woods is making `NMatrix`, which aims to be better than `Matrix`, with Matz's blessing. The asker might check `NMatrix` project, too, and make the same extension gem for it.

Comment: Great input, I cancelled the pull request to the Ruby repo and having a look at NMatrix now, sounds very promising.

Comment: @migu, I was worried I might offend you and I'm glad I haven't. I used to have similar tendencies some time ago. Today, I understand that Ruby gems are part of the language. With `nmatrix` gem, you can give it a thought whether you want to be a part of it, like `nmatrix/extensions`, or have your own `matrix_extensions` gem that would collaborate with both `matrix` and `nmatrix`. Also, you should make your features requireable one by one, as in cherry pickeable, like in `active_support`.

Comment: `NMatrix` requires some complicated OS configuration so I decided to write a gem: https://github.com/michaelimstepf/matrix-extensions

Comment: OK, I'll go there and have some comments. I don't have time to hack on it at the moment, but it falls within my concerns. I'm glad we have a hacker with interest in matrix representations. Ruby severly lacks more science-oriented devs.